# Клиент-сервер. JAVA

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сделать клиент-серверное приложение, но не могу разобраться, почему клиент не обрабатывает команды посланные сервером, но в то же время, сервер может обработать команды, которые посылает клиент.
Код для обработки команд посланных сервером не дописан, потому что даже этот кусок не работает.
**Не обрабатывает именно команды, которые посылает сервер, но если клиент послал команду серверу, то сервер обрабатывает правильно.**

Сервер:

```
public class Server extends Thread{

BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;
ServerSocket server;
Socket client = null;
Frame frame;

Server() throws IOException{
    frame = new Frame();
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(4444);
        frame.textAreaForServer.append("Welcome to server side!\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        frame.textAreaForServer.append("Couldn't listen to port 4444\n");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    addListenerOnTextField();
    this.start();
}

private void clearVector(){
    frame.textAreaForServer.append("-clr\n");
    try {
        //вот я отправляю сообщение клиенту
        out.println("-clr");
        frame.textAreaForServer.append("Vector is cleared\n");
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
        frame.textAreaForServer.append("It's impossible to perform!\n");
    }
}

 public void run(){
    while (true) {
        try {
             //подключение клиента к серверу
            if (client == null) {
                frame.textAreaForServer.append("Waiting for client connection...\n");
                client = server.accept();
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                frame.textAreaForServer.append("Client connected\n");              
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            frame.textAreaForServer.append("Can't accept\n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }            
    }
}
```

Клиент:

```
public class Client extends Thread{

Socket fromserver = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
PrintWriter out;
ControlPanel controlPanel;

Client(ControlPanel controlPanel1) throws IOException {
    controlPanel = controlPanel1;
    addListenerOnTextField();
    this.start();
}

//подключение клиента к серверу
private void connect(ControlPanel controlPanel) {
    controlPanel.textAreaForClient.append("-ct\n");
    if (fromserver == null) {
        controlPanel.textAreaForClient.append("Connecting to localhost...\n");
        try {
            fromserver = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromserver.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(fromserver.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            controlPanel.textAreaForClient.append("Server is not available!\n");
        }
    } else {
        controlPanel.textAreaForClient.append("Already connected\n");
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        //здесь должна обработаться команда "-clr", которую послал сервер
        try {
            switch (in.readLine()) {
                case "-clr": {
                    VectorOfThreads.getInstance().getVectorOfThreads().removeAllElements();
                    controlPanel.textAreaForClient.append("Vector is cleared\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Толкать весь код (у сервера и у клиента) в один файл - очень плохая идея. В результате в файле дикая мешанина из кода, в которой сложно что-либо понять за адекватное время. Разнесите код по классам, а в вопросе оставьте только тот код в том классе, с которым возникает проблема.

Comment: @Regent хорошо, сократил код.

Comment: В представленном коде сервера метод `clearVector` вообще нигде не вызывается. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, в методе `run` не видно обработки каких-либо команд: только подключение одного клиента с последующим уходом в бесконечный цикл, в котором не происходит кроме проверки `if`, в случае успеха.

Comment: @Reget в том то и дело, что это сокращённый код. Если я верну обратно то, что вы просите, то код опять разрастётся до больших размеров. В коде сервера, команды обрабатываются корректно, поэтому я их и не стал включать в предоставленный код. Команды не обрабатываются в методе run() класса Client. Для наглядности, я оставил метод clearVector() в классе Server, который вызывается и выполняется корректно. В общем, проблема в методе run() класса Client, а остальной код для понимания картины происходящего.

Comment: В вопросе должен быть [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). От неработающего кода толка не больше, чем от огромной портянки кода. И предлагал я разбить код на классы не ради вопроса на SO, а ради того, чтобы этот код можно было вменяемо поддерживать и расширять. У вас вот даже сейчас получается, что вы не можете поместить в вопрос только нужный код, ибо при этом всё ломается.

Comment: На стороне сервера, например, каждое действие (обработку конкретной команды) стоит вынести в отдельный файл. Работу с GUI (`Frame`) - ещё в один. Работу с сокетами - ещё в один. Выбор какой класс действия вызывать на основе пришедших данных - ещё в один. Возможно, где-то должны быть классы входных параметров (которые приходят от клиента и парсятся в объект) и выходных данных (которые в классе действия пишутся в объект и затем конвертируются в поток байтов, отправляемых клиенту). `extends Thread` резона делать нет - можно просто создать поток в нужном месте и запустить в нём нужный код/метод.

Comment: @Regent спасибо за совет, в следующий раз учту.

Comment: Если вы корректно разнесёте код, то это увеличит шансы того, что вы сможете отладить программу самостоятельно. А если даже не получится сделать это самому - по крайней мере, будет куда проще создать минимальный воспроизводимый пример проблемы. Полноценного ответа, заметьте, вам никто так и дал. При хорошем примере кода шансы получить ответ на вопрос были бы куда выше.

Comment: @Regent ещё раз спасибо за время, которое вы потратили на меня.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в этом месте `if ("+".equals(in.readLine())) {}` поскольку BufferedReader возвращает строки, и метод equals возвращает true если они идентичны. Прежде всего я не увидел где сервер вообще отправляет этот "+" (Может промограл). Но если вам нужно найти подстроку в строке, то применяйте contains().

Comment: Наверное я плохо составил вопрос. Как раз в первом куске кода всё работает хорошо, не работает кусок кода клиента, который начинается 
с комментария "// начало блока обработки переданных сервером команд".

Comment: У Вас метод называется run() переименуйте его. Это название испольуется при работе с потоками. Скорее всего в этом и заключается ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема не в этом. Я уже от безысходности наследовал класс от Thread и сделал обработку команд в методе run(). До этого всё выполнялось в другом методе, и класс не был наследником Thread, но всё равно ничего не работало.